# Stringify in javascript is returning an empty value

Tags: javascript, html

So I have the following code

```
var email = row.cells[2];
console.log(email);
```

and that returns `<td>jh@hotmail.com</td>`as an object I think however I need that value as a string in order to remove the `<td></td>` I some websites says that I can use JSON.stringify but when i do it like that it returns `{}` anybody knows why?.

Comment: Because it's not a JavaScript object - it's a DOM node. Do `email.textContent` instead.

Comment: everything in javascript is an object, including strings and dom nodes.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. aside from being untrue in general (see: primitives) I was just explaining why JSON.stringify doesn't work.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. doesnt necessarily mean that It can be stringified by JSON methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value that is returned is not just a normal JavaScript object, it's a special one. It is a DOM node, or more specifically a DOM element. It is the way the page is represented in JS.

Because of this, `JSON.stringify()` returns `{}`. Luckily, DOM elements have their own way of getting contents. To get the text content of a DOM element, use `.textContent`. In this case, it would be

```
var DOM_Element = row.cells[2];
var email = DOM_Element.textContent
console.log(email);
```

Consider also `innerHTML`

```
var email = row.cells[2].innerHTML
console.log(email);
```

Credit to **@vlaz**'s comment.

Comment: Ok, so did I get something wrong? I thought this was the right procedure: when someone answers the question in the comments, create a community wiki to say what they said, so the answer can be accepted. Should I have waited longer, or is there some facts I got wrong?

Comment: Not sure what the downvote was about, really. If it is about the comment - I'm perfectly happy with people using it. It's why I left it there. Just couldn't be bothered to post an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var email = row.cells[2].textContent;
```

Comment: remove the stringify, it's not JSON, doesn't need to be stringified.

Comment: Yeah OP caught my attention with that stringify, see edited answer.